# Visual studio edit and continue option not present

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I want to enable edit and continue to be able to edit code while debugging. My visual studio 2015 ultimate does not have the setting in Options>Debugging. I saw some pages talking about disabling Intellitrace but that option is also not present. Why is that?

[image]

I use VS for unity3d and unityvs plugin is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enable Edit and Continue option is at the bottom of Debugging > General:

[image: VS2015 Debugging Options]